# MQTT version 5 publish properties in paho.mqtt.golang?

Tags: go, mqtt, paho

I was reviewing MQTT v5 differences and noticed that "header" information can be published outside the body of the message with user properties.  Is there support for this in paho.mqtt.golang?  Looking at the Publish function, there is only support for client.Publish(topic, qos, retain, message_bytes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`paho.mqtt.golang`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang) only supports MQTT 3/3.1. If you want [properties](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901027), which were introduced in v5, take a look at  [`paho.golang`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.golang) which is a total rewrite that supports MQTT v5 (and v5 only). Support for properties is demonstrated in the [chat example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.golang/blob/master/paho/cmd/chat/main.go):

```
pb := &paho.Publish{
            Topic:   *topic,
            QoS:     byte(*qos),
            Payload: []byte(message),
            Properties: &paho.PublishProperties{
                User: map[string]string{
                    "chatname": *name,
                },
            },
        }
```

Note that while [`paho.golang`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.golang) is fairly stable it does not offer the same level of functionality as [`paho.mqtt.golang`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang) (for example persistence; see [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.golang/issues/26) for more info).